# CodeIgniter Mobile Site Routes

Tags: codeigniter, url, mobile, routes

My site "site.xyz.com" is iframed into client's main website "abc.com". Client wants to have a mobile version of the my site that is loaded in the iframe and they want to decide which user would need to view a mobile version of our site, so they requested a link like site.xyz.com/mobile which will load the mobile site.

My site is already built in CodeIgniter, no .htaccess allowed on the servers. The mobile site has similar html but sizes and images will be little different. So I am planning on using the same MVC structure but a different stylesheet for the mobile site. I am **not** going to check if it is a mobile site or not. any visit to site.xyz.com/mobile should show the mobile version.

I tried `$route['mobile/(:any)'] = '$2';` but then in my code, where I use `base_url()`, it is echoing site.xyz.com/products instead site.xyz.com/mobile/products. Determining if the viewer is seeing desktop/mobile version of the site is also important.

I do not plan on depending on a session/cookie and setting the stylesheet based on the these variables. Future visits might be an issue.

Looks very simple but not getting the right idea... Any tips how I can make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own `base_url()`-function that detects if the user is viewing the mobile site by checking the url used to view that page by checking what [`uri_string()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) returns.

Inside `application/helpers/url_helper.php`:

```
if ( ! function_exists('base_url'))
{
    /**
     * Base URL
     *
     * Create a local URL based on your basepath.
     * Segments can be passed in as a string or an array, same as site_url
     * or a URL to a file can be passed in, e.g. to an image file.
     *
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function base_url($uri = '')
    {
        $currentUri = uri_string(); // Get current URI 
        $currentUri = rtrim($currentUri,'/').'/'; // make sure $uri ends in a '/'
        // If the string begins with 'mobile/', 
        // prepend it to the given array/string
        if(strpos($currentUri,'mobile/') === 0)
        {
            if(is_array($uri)))
                array_unshift($uri,'mobile');
            else
                $uri = 'mobile/'.$uri;
        }

        $CI =& get_instance();
        return $CI->config->base_url($uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually a good idea to refer to the URL and change CSS dynamically. Wouldn't he still have to get his routes to match up as well?

Comment: I believe it should work since he allready tried using `$route['mobile/(:any)'] = '$2';` and it worked except that `base_url()` would give a faulty url.

Comment: Good call, missed that part. I might use this in the future. Good suggestion.

Comment: I added this function, however, the base_url now missing the '/' at the end. my html code is `<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and it retuns as `<script src="http://site.xyz.com/mobilejs/default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`; instead of http://site.xyz.com/mobile/js/default.js

I tried appending .'/' to $uri, but still returns the same. There are a lot of view files on the site and `base_url()` mentions on my site.

Comment: Normally you would do `base_url('js/default.js')`.  The trailing slash probably gets cut out by the last line: `$CI->config->base_url($uri);`

Answer (score 0):

A possible (not entirely pretty) way to do this would be to have a subfolder in your controller folder called "mobile". You can then essentially copy all of your controllers into that directory and change up the paths/logic to suit your mobile site.

According to [CodeIgniter's docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#subfolders), if a controller is in a subfolder, the route will render as *base_url/subfolder/controller/method*. If you are using templates, you can get away with loading the same views as your normal site and just loading a mobile_template.php in your controllers inside the mobile folder.

Seems like more work than you were hoping for, but you will probably have to do more to your mobile site than just change the CSS file anyway.

Comment: Devin - I did consider this option previously, but did not want to go in that direction.

However, out of curiosity to learn, one question - I have many route conditions in my code like `$route['thanks'] ='cart/thanks';`, would there be anything like `$route['(:any)/thanks'] ='$1/cart/thanks';` so that I dont have to replicate each of the route individually, but because currently, they are not pulling in from the mobile sub-folder in controllers.

Comment: Understandable, but you may not have a better option. Dynamically loading a CSS file based on a URL parameter is difficult in itself, but trying to make a mobile site look solid by only changing the CSS file is even more difficult.

Comment: the CSS change I have to do it anyway. But what I want to do is to not replicate the current MVC code and see if there is anyway I can tweak it using routes and provide a cleaner code.